# replique mi server windows a linux y webservice no funciona

Tags: php, webservice, soap, wsdl

replique mi servidor virtual de windows a una maquina en linux.
pero he tenido problemas con levantar un webservice.

ya valide que estuvieran instalados los complementos y funciones de php (xml,soap) y no he logrado levantar.

alguien puede saber a que se puede deber? el único error que tengo es este:

```
 http://192.168.xx.xx/xxxxxxxxx/xx
            Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in C:\AppServ\www\index.php:39 
            Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://DC2MB8P1...', '', 1, 0) #1 
            [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('ZfiWsCecos', Array) #2 C:\AppServ\www\index.php(39): SoapClient->ZfiWsCecos(Array) 
            #3 {main} thrown in C:\AppServ\www\index.php on line 39
```

ya probé liberando la cache y algunos otro métodos y el error continua..

las versiones de php(5.1) y xml y otras son todas iguales ne ambos servidores virtuales..

codigo php:

```
                    $wsdl  = 'http://192.xx.xx.xx:8000/sap/xx/srt/wsdl/xx';


                mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");


                $params = array( 'trace' => true, 
                                 'login' => 'xx',
                                 'password' => 'xx' );

                $sociedades = array( 'xx', 'xx', 'xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx' );

                foreach ($sociedades as $soc ) 
                    {
                    $soap_params = array( 'InBukrs' => $soc, 'GtCecos' => '');

                    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $params );


                $result = $soap->ZfiWsCecos($soap_params);

                if (is_soap_fault($result)) 
                    {
                    echo "OK 1";
                    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring})", E_ERROR);
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                    echo "OK 2";
                    print($client->getQuote($soap_params));
                    }

                //***************




                try{
                        $result = $soap->ZfiWsCecos($soap_params);
                        $result = $result->GtCecos;




                        //Creamos la base del XML y le indicamos que el charset será en latino --
                        $base = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

                        //Creamos un nodo o primer nodo que se llamará XML
                        $body = $base->createElement("GtCecos");

                        //Luego de eso lo anexamos a la base del XML
                        $body = $base->appendChild($body);

                        $item = $base->createElement('item');
                        $body->appendChild( $item );


                        $sociedad = $result->item->Bukrs;
                        $bukrs = $base->createElement('Bukrs', $sociedad);    // sociedad
                        $item->appendChild( $bukrs );



                        $nombre_soc = $result->item->Nomsoc;
                        $Nomsoc = $base->createElement('Nomsoc', $nombre_soc); // nombre_soc
                        $item->appendChild( $Nomsoc );


                        $tareas = $base->createElement('Tareas');
                        $item->appendChild( $tareas );

                        $inItem = $base->createElement('item');
                        $tareas->appendChild( $inItem );

                        foreach( $result->item->Tareas->item as $keys => $values ){
                            $cod_area = $values->Khinr;
                            $nom_area = $values->Nomar;

                            $khir = $base->createElement('Khinr', $cod_area ); 
                               // cod_area
                            $nomar = $base->createElement('Nomar', $nom_area ); 
                              // nom_area
                            $tcecos = $base->createElement('Tcecos');
                            $inItem->appendChild( $khir );
                            $inItem->appendChild( $nomar );
                            $inItem->appendChild( $tcecos );

                            foreach( $values->Tcecos->item  as $val ){
                                $onItem = $base->createElement('item');
                                $tcecos->appendChild($onItem);

                                $cod_cc = $val->Kostl;
                                $Kostl = $base->createElement('Kostl', $cod_cc);     // cod_cc
                                $onItem->appendChild( $Kostl );

                                $nom_cc = $val->Ltext;
                                $Ltext = $base->createElement('Ltext', $nom_cc);     // nom_cc
                                $onItem->appendChild( $Ltext );

                                $fec_inicio = $val->Datab;
                                $Datab = $base->createElement('Datab', $fec_inicio);     // fec_inicio
                                $onItem->appendChild( $Datab );

                                $fec_fin = $val->Datbi;
                                $Datbi = $base->createElement('Datbi', $fec_fin);     // fec_fin
                                $onItem->appendChild( $Datbi );

                                $tag = $val->Bkzkp;
                                $Bkzkp = $base->createElement('Bkzkp', $tag);     // fec_fin
                                $onItem->appendChild( $Bkzkp );





                                $query = "INSERT INTO xx VALUES
                                ()";

                                 mysql_query( $query, $db );
                                 echo '<hr>' . $query;
                                 if( mysql_affected_rows( $db ) <= 0 ){
                                    echo 'Errror de insercion<br>';
                                 }

                            }
                        }

                                //Le pedimos a la base que le de formato
                        $base->formatOutput = true;

                        //pedimos que lo guarde como un archivo
                        $name = 'xml' . $soc . '.xml';
                        $base->save( $name );

                        //abrir XML
                        echo '<script> window.open( xx"_blank" ); </script>';
                    }

                catch( Exception $e ){


                }
                }

                die(); exit;
                // InBukrs,  cl02 
                $response_arr = ZfiWsCecos($myClass1);
```

Comment: `C:\AppServ\www\index.php` parece una ruta de archivo windows, es el que llama al api desde windows? si haces ping desde consola a `192.168.xx.xx` te responde? si pones `http://192.168.xx.xx/` en el navegador te carga la página default de apache / el default del api ?

Comment: @aloMalbarez hice un ping desde el linux y desde el windows, y en ambos llego a la ip del wsdl, solo hice el ping ala ip, no al link completo.

Comment: bien 1/3, ping a enlaces no es posible ( es enviar un paquete de red para ver si hay problemas de conectividad ) , las otras 2 preguntas que ondas? si pones la url en un navegador que aparece?

Comment: @aloMalbarez si pongo la url completa en el navegador, me solicita loguearme para entrar al xml, en ambas abre ok y logueo ok. pineso que es una funcion de la `DLL` que no esta haciendo bien su trabajo..

Comment: ok, habrá que ver código ( anonimizando cosas ) para ver si hay algo que el script que replicaste asume estar en win y no en linux, pero antes de pegar monton de código: cómo es la movida? desde win a win funciona y ahora desde win a linux no funciona? es asi?

Comment: nota adicional php 5.1 es medio como un accidente esperando que pase, 5.3 es mas estable y 5.6 si el salto a 7.x requiere mucho es lo mas recomendable, 5.1 es de hace bastante [fin de soporte: 24 Agosto 2006](https://www.php.net/eol.php) la diferencia en el consumo de memoria y velocidad de ejecución es muy notable entre 5.1 5.3 y 5.6, y comparado a 7.3  es otro mundo

Comment: @aloMalbarez exacto de win a win funciona, te adjunto codigo.

Comment: chequea  tu wsdl  si cambiastes la ip o el dominio el WSDL se debe generar nuevamente

Comment: @aloMalbarez el problema estaba en el hostname , tenia tipeado una letra de mas :) gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema estaba en el Hostname del nuevo server, se había creado y tenia una letra de mas...